# multiple patterns in awk match

Tags: unix, awk

This is a snippet of my script that prints the record of a file if the value of second column is "THWR". I need to add "RWGW" and "OSPW" into the match criteria. Is this possible with awk's match function?

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]*")' 'NR==1; NR>1 && match($2,"THWR")
```

sample intput:

```
col1,col2,col3
123,THWR,123
123,RWGW,123
123,OSPW,123
123,POOL,123
123,TYTY,123
```

desired output:

```
col1,col2,col3
123,THWR,123
123,RWGW,123
123,OSPW,123
```

As much as possible I would like to do this via `awk` match.

Comment: Please add sample input and sample output into your post in code tags and let me know on same then.

Comment: hi ravi. edited my post.

Comment: hi, your output needed doesn't make any sense please be more clear on your question and let us know more detailed information.

Comment: hi. sorry but i made it as simple as possible. basically the output should be the lines with  "THWR" "RWGW" and "OSPW" values on the second column.

Comment: ok, got your requirement now, please check my solution and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you. You could give n number of strings in variable named `var` with comma delimited.

```
awk -F, -v var="THWR,RWGW,OSPW" 'BEGIN{num=split(var, array,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){array1[array[i]]}} $2 in array1'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, -v var="THWR,RWGW,OSPW" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(var, array,",");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){  array1[array[i]]  }
}
$2 in array1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
123,THWR,123
123,RWGW,123
123,OSPW,123
```

Comment: will do. can you please explain your solution? thank you

Comment: @user2058738, I haven't tested it since you didn't give any samples, please add proper samples and I will re-write command for you then.

Comment: @user2058738, could you please check my edited code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: I've tried and got the correct output using this. Thank you Ravi

Answer (score 0):

@RavinderSingh13's approach is proper and reusable but sometimes you just want to check the field value for a couple (or three in this case) of candidates. In that case use:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 || $2 ~ /^(THWR|RWGW|OSPW)$/' file
col1,col2,col3
123,THWR,123
123,RWGW,123
123,OSPW,123
```